# Outer div won't expand when slide-in menu height changes

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, css-float, clearfix

Can anyone help me out with this? I've tried clear fix and a number of other things but cannot figure out why the container column (center one) which contains the slide-in navigation menu won't auto adjust its height. Code pen of non working code below.

https://codepen.io/GerdSuhr/pen/ERprWQ?editors=0110

```
.clear:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Container div height not resizing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746547/container-div-height-not-resizing)

Answer (score 0):

Because the content is absolute. You need to rethink that styling. Try removing the

```
position: absolute
```

from

```
.dl-menuwrapper .dl-menu
```

and you'll see it will auto adjust.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to figure it out.